# docker-machine instance not running on port 8080

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-machine

I am trying to get [this](http://dapperdeveloper.com/2016/05/18/developing-with-docker-and-webpack/) tutorial to work. But at the end of the tutorial it says to run  http://192.168.99.100:8080 and see your website. But it is not showing up for me at all after running docker-machine ls. There are no entries at all. So my question is how can I get a docker-machine instance running on an nginx container? I assume that is the one that runs the wwwroot folder, that is what points to it and has all of the port and root calls for the server. 
My code in the docker-compose.yml is the same as the tutorial but here it is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker.nginx
    image: my-nginx
    container_name: my-nginx-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - wwwroot:/wwwroot
  webpack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker.webpack
    image: my-webpack
    container_name: my-webpack-container
    ports:
      - "35729:35729"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - wwwroot:/wwwroot
volumes:
  wwwroot:
    driver: local
```

Comment: It might be possible that docker fails to run when you run `docker-compose up --build -d`. Try running without `-d` flag and see if the container starts. Just to make sure, have you tried `localhost:8080`?

Comment: I am getting forbidden nginx 403 error when running localhost:8080

Comment: also getting the following error without detached mode:
directory index of "/wwwroot/" is forbidden, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"

Comment: This configuration would be in `nginx.conf` which must be present in the same folder when you are building the image

Comment: well, I am able to hit the website now. Thanks for your help @Ayushya. I had to copy over a file into my wwwroot for index.html. The tutorial doesn't have any files or folder structure, so I am sort of making it up. I wonder how I need to set up jsx files on my box to see the transpiling happen?

Comment: I am not much familiar with `jsx` files or its transpiling, however, I can recommend you to get shell access into the container using `dokcer exec -it <container_name> bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it has been established that your docker machine is running and the server you are trying to run is running on `localhost:8080`.

Before you run `docker compose up`, make sure that the directory contains other required files and folders, example`nginx.conf` and `index.html`.

Comment: marking this correct, but nginx.conf was already there, that was not the issue. index.html was a bigger issue.